# Is it correct to delete a button that opens a section, when the section is open?

Tags: gui-design, buttons, best-practice, intuition, visibility

In a particular scenario, I have a button in the main window of application that, when pressed, opens a specific "command" section. When this section is open, is it correct to **delete** the button that opens the section (and make it visible again when the section will be closed), or is it better to **maintaine it visible** (with no effect)?

We have not graphical constraints: I am asking myself if there is a general 
UI-best practice and intuitive answer for this question, or it depends (if so, by what).

Many thanks.

Comment: I think it depends on the topic, the situation and name of the button? Is it possible to upload an image, because I can't really visualise the issue.

Comment: This sounds like it would be better served as a moral rather then a section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this kind of scenario a lot in my actual job. I think buttons which dissapears when you press it and toggle some menu could lead to the user having FUD (Fear, Uncertainty and Doubt). "Where is the button? Why it dissapears? How I can hide the new menu? Am I breaking the app?"

Toggle information or functionability isn't bad, but we need to be careful about changing flows and hiding things. I can advice you about having a dropdown button wich displays the command section when you click (in general terms. I don't know the exact case you need an answer) and give that button some style in order to let the user know the button is pressed.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot. For that cases, I am reasoning about another option, that is positioning the button exactly in the area of the section that it will open. In that case, when the user press it, the second section overlay the button and the user could be quite "sure" that he has to close the section to see the button reappears again. What do you think about it?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand that idea, but I think that case leads to the same thing. The button became hidden with something. The main point is something like the examples JQuery give in toggle. https://api.jquery.com/toggle/

You have a button, you click it and the info appears below that. If you want to hide it, you can press it and hide it. In all moment, the button is at plain sight

Answer (score 1):

What is your motivation for creating a nonstandard interface with a disappearing button? **It's too similar to prank apps** that move buttons around and make them disappear when users try to click them. Far better to gray them out, if you wish to deactivate them, for instance.

What you describe seems similar to a tree view or opening a section of a document, such as on Wikipedia. **The usual behavior is for the "button" to change appearance** when the section is opened. For instance, [+] may change to [-], or a triangle may turn.

Answer (score 0):

This will probably depend on the context, but it's my impression that the most common pattern is to keep the button and the let another click or tap remove the element it added. For instance the menu button in your browser and on this site will behave in this way.

Answer (score 0):

**Technically:**

In Angular for example if you can't track the action you can't know when to show the button or hide it, so developers, in general, keep it existing since you clicked it and got the action.

Most of the cases it's difficult on the developer to judge on-fly results and build action (ex: Show or hide a button) so they use to keep it existing all the time. And instead, show a popup informative message.

**Logically:**

Logically, regardless of the possibility to show or hide. I think Instead of hiding the button you can disable it and give it a gray color, this indicates that the button can't be used. I don't recommend deleting it totally.